# jQuery - strict children hierachy selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

What would the equivalent of the following jQuery selector:

```
$('table.special > thead > tr')
```

be if I had `$('table.special')` as a `$table` argument in function to start with?

(something of the form `$table.(...)` but equivalent to the first mentioned selector)

---

**Note**: `$table.filter('thead > tr')` is *not* what I want, as it also selects `thead` element of nested tables, and `$table.filter('> thead > tr')` doesn't work and neither `$table.children('thead > tr')`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
$table.children("thead").children("tr");
```

As well as:

```
$table.find("> thead > tr");
// or
$("> thead > tr", $table);
```

but for some reasons this type of selector is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) now.

Comment: thanks! ...dunno where my head was, used `filter` instead of `find` ...though it really puzzles me why would they deprecate something as useful as this (actually "will be deprecated in a future release" which makes even less sense to have in the docs)

Comment: @NeuronQ The latter is more or less understandable: maybe they want us to get out of the habit of using these features even now.

Comment: the first one is definitely *less* understandable when you have smth like I do: `$table.find('> thead > tr > td:nth-child(6) > .title a')` ...4+ calls to `children` look anything but nice... but I got my answer so let's move on:)